# Override default implementation of AddressChoiceType

Tags: symfony4, pimcore, coreshop

I have a final class AddressChoiceType in CoreShop vendor folder file vendor/coreshop/core-shop/src/CoreShop/Bundle/CoreBundle/Form/Type/AddressChoiceType.php
I need to change default implementation of setting choice_label on line 81 from:

```
return sprintf('%s %s', $address->getStreet(), $address->getNumber());
```

to:

```
return sprintf('%s %s %s %s', $address->getPostcode(), $address->getCity(), $address->getStreet(), $address->getNumber());
```

Is it any good way to do it?

Comment: Which version / SHA of PimCore are you referring to? I could not find a version where tha line is on line 81 (just before).

Comment: @JimmyBlu I have Pimcore CMS Version: v6.9.3 and CoreShop Version 2.2.9